# Cannot launch Lollypop music player after installing from a deb package on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: music-player

I am trying to install Lollypop on a new Linux install 16.04 LTS.  When I run

```
sudo apt-get install lollypop
```

I get the error 'file not found'. (Yes, I added the repo)

I found a deb package online and installed that but Lollypop would run for a second then close.

Can't find any info on this problem after looking for a couple of hours.  Any ideas?

The original info I used to install Lollypop I found [here](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/11/how-to-install-lollypop-music-player-in-ubuntu-16-04/). I found the Xenial package [here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_apps/xenial/apps/getdeb/lollypop) and installed using GDebi.

Comment: The first thing to figure out that kind of error is to run `lollypop` from the command line and see what error messages you get.

Comment: Lollypop : https://launchpad.net/~gnumdk/+archive/ubuntu/lollypop ... Or install the downloaded package : `cd Downloads/ && sudo gdebi ./lollypop_*_amd64.deb`

Comment: Sorry that was not a great post.
Yes - sudo apt-get install lollypop

The error I get is:   E:unable to locate package

Comment: Sorry that was not a great post. 
Yes - sudo apt-get install lollypop was the command I used. 
Yes - did run sudo apt-get update (upgrade as well). 
The repository is hit when I run update. 
The error I get is:   E:unable to locate package lollypop. 
Can't run Lollypop from command line. 
I went to the site that Knud Larsen posted - I cannot find a package  for Xenial
Thanks

Comment: also, I could not find the xenial package in the ppa that is in the instructions I found on the web. -
 ppa:gnumdk/lollypop

Comment: Could someone please verify that I am correct that the package for Xenial in not in the repo?  I want to mark this post as answered but answer does not contain reference to this problem.  The first problem I had was - E:unable to locate package lollypop. I downloaded the .deb package from another source. Then I solved the GTK problem.  Thanks

Comment: I was recently contacted by the developer that the xenial package is back in the repository

Answer (score 3):

Running `lollypop` from the CLI gives an error that GTK+ 3.20 is needed, the current installed version was 3.18.
A way to upgrade 3.18 to 3.20 can be found [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/05/install-gnome-3-20-ubuntu-16-04-lts).
Adding two repos by the following commands and updating should trigger a bunch of packages that needed to be updated. Note that you'll be installing untested packages and  if you intend to switch between Unity and GNOME you should expect some compromise on the Unity half.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Reboot and Lollypop should be running now.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you [may "accept" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking on the tick mark (✓) next to it) so others may more easily find it in the future. Accepting your own answer is completely fine :)